# Why can't my program find the libraries in "/usr/local/lib"?

Tags: libraries, shared-library, opencv

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10, and I've just upgraded opencv to 2.4.2.

The problem is that each time I open a new shell and try to compile and run, it compiles but doesn't run due to the following error:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

As far as I can see, this file is located in /usr/local/lib/!

I can get it to run by running the following beforehand:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67781/use-shared-libraries-in-usr-local-lib

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/usr/local/lib` is not in the default Ubuntu path. You should add it at the end of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in `/etc/environment`. Reboot and the new path will be effective.

You can also set this on a per-user basis in ~/.bashrc

#### Example (/etc/environment)

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

#### Example (~/.bashrc)

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib"
```

Comment: I upvoted, but actually it seems like running `ldconfig` as root is the "right" way to do this: http://askubuntu.com/a/350076/221408

Comment: [It's best to avoid setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` permanently.](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html)

Comment: I downvoted (and upvoted @j_random_hacker's  ldconfig response), because `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is almost always the wrong answer to linker errors and should come with extensive caveats.  Just type `sudo ldconfig`.