# Execute a program in guest session

Tags: 14.04, guest-session

I downloaded [Spriter](http://brashmonkey.com/download_spriter/) for `Linux 64bit` then move it to `usr/share/` and extract it. There is a file in extracted directory that is executable and can run by `context menu >> run`. I want to enable running that file for Guest user. In `Guest Session` I can browse to that directory but when I select `run` from context menu, application does not run. How I can solve this problem?

Edit:

Before I changed the permission of that file to be accessible for `others` for `READ and WRITE`.

You can see result of `ls -l` for that file:

```
ls -l Spriter
-rwxrwxrwx 1 myUserName myUserName 7102491 فوریه  7 18:56 Spriter
```

The result of `./Spriter` in terminal is:

```
error while loading shared libraries:libsteam_api.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It's hard to to tell why something doesn't run, without knowing what it is.

Comment: @mikewhatever I add more details  to question, I downloaded `Spriter for Linux 64bit`

Comment: So, you've changed the permissions to rw but not x (execute)? Usually, x is required to run something. You may want to post the output of `ls -l thatfile`.

Comment: @mikewhatever I add the result of command . Please see it .

Comment: @mikewhatever please see my edits again.

Comment: So, assuming `libsteam_api.so` is there and is readable, you can try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/share/etc...`. Not sure if guest is allowed to do it.

Comment: Possibly [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/350068/where-does-ubuntu-look-for-shared-libraries) is applicable.

Comment: OK!  `libsteam_api.so` is a file in the extracted `Spriter` directory and its permission for other users was `unknown`. I changed it to `READ and WRITE`. Now `Guest` can run Application. Thank you!

Comment: @mikewhatever, your solution worked for hasanghaforian, could you write an answer.