# fslview not running in Ubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, libraries, shared-library, image-processing

I have installed `fsl` in Ubuntu 16.04 and when I type `fslview` I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fslview_bin: error while loading shared libraries: libmng.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: I can't find a `libmng.so.1`, bu there's a [`libmng.so` in the `libmng-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libmng-dev/filelist) package.

Comment: Did not get it?

Comment: @Ali What does "Did not get it?" mean? How is fslview installed? If it shipped its own copy of the library, ensure it's in an appropriate place, and run `sudo ldconfig`. See [Where does Ubuntu look for shared libraries?](https://askubuntu.com/q/350068) As muru says, `libmng.so.1` isn't in 16.04. But a later version, `libmng.so.2`, [is in the `libmng2` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libmng2/filelist). Assuming you've compiled fslview, you're best off recompiling it against that version if you can. Please [add more information to your question](https://askubuntu.com/q/866786).

Comment: Sorry Eliah, I meant to say that I did not understand what you have suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try installing package `libmng2` since `libmng1` is for ubuntu precise and below

```
sudo apt-get install libmng2
```

Else if the package already exist,try linking to `libmng.so.2`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmng.so.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmng.so.1
```

Comment: In my case, the exact command were: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libmng.so.2 /usr/lib64/libmng.so.1` on OpenSUSE