# error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_lp64.so

Tags: 18.04, intel, shared-library

I executed a program and I got an error message as follows:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So, it seems that this program requires `mkl` library. I followed the instructions indicated here:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl-download.html?operatingsystem=linux&distributions=online

Meaning that I executed:

```
wget https://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/19038/l_onemkl_p_2022.2.1.16993.sh
sudo sh ./l_onemkl_p_2022.2.1.16993.sh
```

Now, the installation location is at: /opt/intel/oneapi/

I can see that there is a folder called `mkl` in the above folder. However, I still don't see libmkl_intel_lp64.so and the execution of the program still leads to the same error message as previously mentioned.

Could you please tell me what should be done to not have this error?

P.S.: I have Linux 18.04

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/350068/where-does-ubuntu-look-for-shared-libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing step was the execution of the following command:

```
source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
```