# squeak: could not find any display driver

Tags: drivers, libraries, shared-library, dynamic-linking, static-linking

I am building the vm for squeak on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit. It is failing to call entry points to libraries, whether these libraries are statically linked or loaded or not loaded. I have been doing some research through other questions and found 4 related questions, but neither an exported LD_LIBRARY_PATH, nor running 'sudo ldconfig' helps:

- [Where does Ubuntu look for shared libraries?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350068/where-does-ubuntu-look-for-shared-libraries)
- [Why can't my program find the libraries in "/usr/local/lib"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165027/why-cant-my-program-find-the-libraries-in-usr-local-lib?lq=1)
- [OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems. (steam) AMD DRIVER](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506349/opengl-glx-context-is-not-using-direct-rendering-which-may-cause-performance-pr)
- [Ubuntu 14.04 “could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'!"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539858/ubuntu-14-04-could-not-find-required-opengl-entry-point-glgeterror)

I noticed this calling dynamic linked libraries squeak also builds, then it fails to find a display driver wwe also build. (More at squeakvm.org).

```
$ squeak Mushroom.1.image &
[2] 3107
$ squeak: could not find any display driver

[2]+  Aborted                 (core dumped) squeak Mushroom.1.image
```

I also build several of our plugins internally and these also failed to be called at runtime. Doing a nm -a squeak gave many symbols, but some, not all, of the symbols from various statically linked libraries were present.

Could an issue with symbol binding be affecting both static and dynamic cases? Are there other reports of problems with library runtime and other recommendations?

---

Update:

Here are the libraries I've loaded to a fresh install of 15.10 32-bit.

> ## INSTALL BUILD LIBRARIES
>
> ======================================================
>
> sudo apt-get install cmake zip bash-completion git
>
> sudo apt-get install libc6-dev:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-dev:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
>
> sudo apt-get install libssl-dev:i386 libssl0.9.8:i386 libfreetype6-dev:i386
>
> sudo apt-get install libx11-dev:i386 libsm-dev:i386 libice-dev:i386
>
> sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc-multilib g++
>
> sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
>
> sudo apt-get install binutils:i386 g++-4.6:i386 gcc-4.6:i386
>
> sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
>
> sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
>
> sudo apt-get install uuid-dev:i386
>
> sudo apt-get install subversion

where squeak fails to find the display driver after running sudo ldconfig -v. Something in there is breaking, I believe. I will do another install and not run any of these and slowly start a little at a time.

---

regards,
robert

Comment: It happened once again. I actually have a 15.10 32-bit Ubuntu installed, having just reinstalled again. My standard startup of an install is a few apps and this script prior to pulling the vm code to building the initial images by running a binary of squeak's vm.

Comment: Please note that I also upgraded the system over the web when installing and also when the dialog prompts me. I did both here.